# Linker Error Lua 5.1

Tags: c++, c, linker, lua

I'm compiling something basic with the Lua library, and keep getting a Undefined Reference Error for *certain* methods.

Not all methods have problems, only loadfile and set/getglobal. I tried replacing set/getglobal with the expanded Macro, but the I get a "LUA_GLOBALSINDEX' was not declared in this scope". Commenting out the offending methods however does allow the file to compile.

The command I use to compile is:

```
g++ /sourcefiles/ -Wall  -lncurses -llua5.1 -lm -ldl
```

Comment: Are you sure your Lua headers are for Lua 5.1, not for 5.2?

Comment: @lhf yes, I included them as lua5.1/lua.hpp, and I haven't got lua 5.2

Comment: apparently, removing and reinstalling helped.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that LUA_GLOBALSINDEX is a `#define`? Defines are not linked from lib files.

Comment: That should have been a comment, not an answer.